# C# CefSharp переделать кусочек кода не используя string.Join

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Код ниже перебирает все ссылки на странице и выводит их в текстбокс

```
string script = @"(function()
                        {
                            var linksArray = new Array();
                            for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++)
                            {
                                linksArray[i] = [String(document.links[i].innerHTML),
                                        String(document.links[i].innerText),
                                        String(document.links[i].href)];
                            }
                            return linksArray;
                        })();";
            var task = chrome.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
            task.ContinueWith(x =>
            {
                var response = x.Result;
                if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
                {
                    var list = (List<object>)response.Result;
                    string s = "";
                    foreach (List<object> item in list)
                    {
                        s = string.Join("\n", item.Select(item1 => $"{item1}"));
                            textHtml.Text += s + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Как переделать строку кода (см. ниже)

```
s = string.Join("\n", item.Select(item1 => $"{item1}"));
```

используя обычные foreach, if и т.д. пусть даже код будет длинным, главное не использовать "string.Join" и другие продвинутые темы.

Comment: string.join это не продвинутая тема, это база. на одном уровне с циклами, условиями и какими-нибудь операциями сложения/вычитания, так что не придумывайте и используйте string.join. Но к слову, можете через цикл foreach перебрать элементы коллекции и добавлять их в StringBuilder

Comment: @Aarnihauta, можете показать пример, как переделать этот код через foreach?

Comment: А можно вопрос, зачем? Вы уверены, что вам нужен целый браузер для того, чтобы реализовать вашу задачу?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в этом случае интересует только строка с  string.Join, можно ли переделать эту сроку используя лишь foreach, if, без использования stringBuilder-а и string.Join-а

Comment: Вы наверно не поняли мой вопрос, ок, перефразирую - Вы уверены, что вам нужен полноценный браузер, в котором вы выполните некий скрипт, после чего получите нужные данные для вашего проекта? Если вы парсите сайт, то я на 90% уверен, что там браузер не нужен, если вам нужно просто поиграться с JS, то есть отдельны механизмы, которые выполняют код локально, без браузера. Так что, повторю, вы уверены, что вам нужен CefSharp?

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос только в написании аналога Join, то это, конечно, возможно, но есть ли в этом смысл для вашей программы? Вот я вам пример набросал:

```
string LikeJoin(string separator, string[] arr) {
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   int len = arr.Length;
   for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
      sb.Append(arr[i]);
      if (i != len - 1) 
         sb.Append(separator);
   }
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

Так же Select с интерполяцией можно заменить на Cast

```
item.Cast<string>()
```

Но если вас волнует оптимизация, то подумайте лучше над самим методом парсинга.

Comment: без StringBuilder-а нельзя переделать?

Comment: Если мы в цикле выполняем конкатенацию строк, то у нас каждый раз в памяти новая строка висит. Поэтому это не тот случай, когда неиспользование класса даст выигрыш.

Comment: Но если вам очень хочется, то делайте str += arr[i]